# storing certain fields encrypted in postgres with pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, encryption, pgcrypto

The [postgres docs on "Encryption Options"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/encryption-options.html) say:

> Encryption For Specific Columns
>
> The pgcrypto module allows certain fields to be stored encrypted. This is useful if only some of the data is sensitive. The client supplies the decryption key and the data is decrypted on the server and then sent to the client.
>
> The decrypted data and the decryption key are present on the server for a brief time while it is being decrypted and communicated between the client and server. This presents a brief moment where the data and keys can be intercepted by someone with complete access to the database server, such as the system administrator.

"pgcrypto" is linked to the [pgcrypto docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html), which discuss a variety of available hashing and encryption functions.

But it's not clear to me how I'm meant to put them together to implement the solution the "Encryption Options" docs suggested, to allow certain fields (ie columns) to be stored encrypted. I am having trouble finding any docs or examples.

Can anyone point me to doc or examples explaining how you use pgcrypto to allow certain fields to be stored encrypted?